# Adding row on click in bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is working fine but the  label is not in right position. On click first label is not in right position but others are in right position.

Where am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Field:1</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var info = 1;
    function add_fields() {
        info++;
        var objTo = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0]
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-3     
        control-label">Field'+info+'</label><div class="col-lg-5"> <input   
        type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" /></div></div>';
        objTo.appendChild(divtest)
    }
    </script>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can check it here.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwKJrV

Answer (score 1):

The row is being appended to the wrong place. Try:

```
<div id="additionalFields"></div>
```

where you want the new fields to be, and then changing

```
var objTo = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0]
```

to

```
var objTo = document.getElementById('additionalFields');
```

This should correct the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your bootsrap column.

```
<form>

  <div class="form-group ">
   <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Field:1</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" />
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var info = 1;
    function add_fields() {
    info++;
    var objTo = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0]
    console.log(objTo);

       var divtest = document.createElement("div");
     divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Field'+info+'</label><div class="col-lg-9"> <input type="text"         class="form-control" name="field1" /></div></div>';

     objTo.appendChild(divtest)
     }
```

you can take it as a reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: total column should be 12. You have 8 columns (col-lg-3 and col-lg-5). So the next col-lg-3 is appended to the same row

Comment: Thanks. Working fine. But there is no gap between the rows.

Comment: you can add a row class with form-group class

Comment: Well, Can I add form validation? How I change the name value of form as and when I add a row on click..

Comment: Will it work? <div class="col-lg-9"> <input type="text"         class="form-control"    name="field1'+info='" />